# Msal v2 library, handle logout for SSO (Node.js and Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

### The problem:

Using msal v2, when user log in to the app via Microsoft account, it saves params to the `sessionStorage` and it all works great, problem happens when user logs out in the Office.com or any other site using Microsoft SSO. Since the data is still saved in `sessionStorage` (tried same with `localStorage`) the `AcquireSilentToken(...)` resolves with the cached data, even though the user has been logged out.

Tried [How to know if a given user is already logged in with MSAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346058/how-to-know-if-a-given-user-is-already-logged-in-with-msal)

It suggest using `AcquireSilentToken(...)` but it resolves promise without error since it checks `sessionStorage`.

### My case:

In the middleware I would like to do:

```
const promise = msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes);
  promise.then(resp=>{
    //User is logged continue next();
      }).catch(error=>{
    //User is not logged in clear sessionStorage/localStorage and next('/login')
  });
```

So if anyone can help me with the way of asking the thru msal if user has logged out. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. AAD services uses cookies to remember who you are and to automatically sign you in.

The sign-out process for services forces the session cookies to expire. These session cookies are used to maintain your sign-in state when you use these services. However, because the web browser is still running and may not be updated to handle cookies correctly, you may have a cookie that is not updated to expire and finish the sign-out process. By default, these cookies are valid for eight hours or are set to expire when you close all web browsers.

```
const promise = msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes);
  promise.then(resp=>{
    const logoutRequest = {
           account: instance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId),
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "your_app_logout_redirect_uri"
}
instance.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);
  }).catch(error=>{
//User is not logged in clear sessionStorage/localStorage and next('/login')
```

});

Also this is a known [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/sign-in/cannot-sign-out-cloud-service).

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is a known issue. It happens even with their own web application like Outlook.